# Vertical scrolling with div in html/css

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html style="height: 100%; width: 100%; ">
<head>
<STYLE type=text/css>
.startupbody     {border-style: none; border:0; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #00ff00;  overflow:hidden; }

.div1{width: 100%; height: 40px;   border: 0px; background-color: #ff0000; overflow:hidden; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.div2{width: 100%; height: 100%;   border: 0px; background-color: #0000ff; overflow:auto;   margin: 0; padding: 0;}

</STYLE>
</head>
<body class="startupbody">
<div class="div1">
First division
</div>
<div class="div2">
line 1<br>
line 2<br>
line 3<br>
line 4<br>
line 5<br>
line 6<br>
line 7<br>
line 8<br>
line 9<br>
line 10<br>
line 11<br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have 2 divs. The first is a header that has a fixed size in pixels. 
This one should not scroll.
The second div is below the first div and contains the data. The second one should occupy the rest of window. If there is more data then can be displayed the second div should scroll.
Both divs should horizontally occupy the complete window. 
How do I code this in html/css. 
So far I have

It does almost what I want, except for one thing. The scrollbar in the second div doesn't work correct. The toolbar is't displayed completely and I can't 
scroll all the way down.

Comment: `overflow: auto` do what you want. Just insert more data and you will see that the scroll appears.

Comment: works pretty well: https://jsfiddle.net/a3et8d03/1/

Answer (score 0):

Specify the height to your second div.

**CSS:**

```
.div2 {
    width: 100%;
    border: 0px;
    background-color: #00F;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100px;
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dinker/tvk1Lz1n/)

Note : here I have hardcoded the height you can set your own height.

Comment: jsFiddle, The height of the second div was allready specified (100%).

Comment: JsFiddle, the height of seconde div was allready specified to 100% and when I use a fixed size in pixels the second div doesn't occopy the rest of the window.

Comment: The solution using calc works great, but is there a solution that works in I.E. 7 as well? The htmlpage is normally displayed in a custom browser written in visual basic that uses I.E.7 by default. I know how I can force the custom browser to use I.E. 11 (by adding some registry entries), but a lot of my users still effectively use I.E. 7, and other pages of the same project project aren't ready for a higher version of I.E. .

Answer (score 0):

You can use just `calc()` function to substract the `40px` height of the header, test it:

The change is in the height of `.div2`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html style="height: 100%; width: 100%; ">
<head>
<STYLE type=text/css>
.startupbody     {border-style: none; border:0; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #00ff00;  overflow:hidden; }

.div1{width: 100%; height: 40px;   border: 0px; background-color: #ff0000; overflow:hidden; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.div2{width: 100%; height: calc(100% - 40px);   border: 0px; background-color: #0000ff; overflow:auto;   margin: 0; padding: 0;}

</STYLE>
</head>
<body class="startupbody">
<div class="div1">
First division
</div>
<div class="div2">
line 1<br>
line 2<br>
line 3<br>
line 4<br>
line 5<br>
line 6<br>
line 7<br>
line 8<br>
line 9<br>
line 10<br>
line 11<br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

`calc()` it's now wide compatible with most current browsers:

http://caniuse.com/#search=calc

Answer (score 0):

`overflow: auto` will bring the scroll bar whenever content overflows the container.

Modify `div2` height like `height: calc(100% - 40px);`. This will set `div2` height as (***100% - height of `div1`***). Also avoids the bottom of scroll bar being hidden.

[image] [image]

Bottom of scroll bar being **visible**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html style="height: 100%; width: 100%; ">

<head>
  <STYLE type=text/css>
    .startupbody {
      border-style: none;
      border: 0;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: #00ff00;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .div1 {
      width: 100%;
      height: 40px;
      border: 0px;
      background-color: #ff0000;
      overflow: hidden;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .div2 {
      width: 100%;
      height: calc(100% - 40px);
      border: 0px;
      background-color: #0000ff;
      overflow: auto;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  </STYLE>
</head>

<body class="startupbody">
  <div class="div1">
    First division
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    line 1
    <br>line 2
    <br>line 3
    <br>line 4
    <br>line 5
    <br>line 6
    <br>line 7
    <br>line 8
    <br>line 9
    <br>line 10
    <br>line 11
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Bottom of scroll bar being **hidden**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html style="height: 100%; width: 100%; ">

<head>
  <STYLE type=text/css>
    .startupbody {
      border-style: none;
      border: 0;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: #00ff00;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .div1 {
      width: 100%;
      height: 40px;
      border: 0px;
      background-color: #ff0000;
      overflow: hidden;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .div2 {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border: 0px;
      background-color: #0000ff;
      overflow: auto;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  </STYLE>
</head>

<body class="startupbody">
  <div class="div1">
    First division
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    line 1
    <br>line 2
    <br>line 3
    <br>line 4
    <br>line 5
    <br>line 6
    <br>line 7
    <br>line 8
    <br>line 9
    <br>line 10
    <br>line 11
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```